# Specify which shell to use in R

Tags: r, bash, shell

I have to run a shell script inside R. I've considered using R's `system` function.

However, my script involves `source activate` and other commands that are not available in /bin/sh shell. Is there a way I can use /bin/bash instead?

Thanks!

Comment: yes: `system("/bin/bash my_script.sh")`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Invoke `/bin/bash`, and pass the commands via `-c` option in one of the following ways:

```
system(paste("/bin/bash -c", shQuote("Bash commands")))
system2("/bin/bash", args = c("-c", shQuote("Bash commands")))
```

If you only want to run a Bash *file*, supply it with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash -
builtin printf %q "/tmp/a b c"
```

and call it by passing script's path to the `system` function:

```
system("/path/to/script.sh")
```

It is implied that the current user/group has sufficient [permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions) to execute the script.

### Rationale

Previously I suggested to set the `SHELL` environment variable. But it probably won't work, since the implementation of the `system` function in R calls [the C function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) with the same name (see [`src/main/sysutils.c`](https://svn.r-project.org/R/tags/R-3-2-2/src/main/sysutils.c)):

```
int R_system(const char *command)
{
    /*... */
    res = system(command);
```

And

> The  `system()`  library  function  uses `fork(2)` to create a child process that executes the shell command specified in command using `execl(3)` as follows:
>
> `execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) 0);`

*(see `man 3 system`)*

Thus, you should invoke `/bin/bash`, and pass the script body via the `-c` option.

### Testing

Let's list the top-level directories in `/tmp` using the Bash-specific `mapfile`:

*test.R*

```
script <- '
mapfile -t dir < <(find /tmp -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)
for d in "${dir[@]}"
do
  builtin printf "%s\n" "$d"
done > /tmp/out'

system2("/bin/bash", args = c("-c", shQuote(script)))
```

*test.sh*

```
Rscript test.R && cat /tmp/out
```

*Sample Output*

```
/tmp/RtmpjJpuzr
/tmp/fish.ruslan
...
```

### Original Answer

Try to set the `SHELL` environment variable:

```
Sys.setenv(SHELL = "/bin/bash")
system("command")
```

Then the commands passed to `system` or `system2` functions should be invoked using the specified shell.

Comment: I tried your last option, but still doesn't work (in my case, I'm trying to set zsh, which is the default in my macOS). Actually, if I run "Sys.getenv("SHELL")", I get "/bin/zsh", but commands passed with system() still use bash.

Comment: @FranVillamil, Have you tried putting the shell command(s) into an executable file with the shebang and then invoking it through `system("/path/to/script.sh")`?

Comment: Yes, but I still have trouble. I think it might be related to this (https://superuser.com/questions/1642933/r-and-shell-in-macos-catalina) and something I don't understand about the shell.