# R system() error when using brace expansion to match folders in linux

Tags: r, linux, bash, glob

I have a series of sequential directories to gather files from on a linux server that I am logging into remotely and processing from an R terminal.

/r18_060, /r18_061, ... /r18_118, /r18_119

Each directory is for the day of year the data was logged on, and it contains a series of files with standard prefix such as "fl.060.gz"

I have to supply a function that contains multiple system() commands with a linux glob for the day. I want to divide the year into 60-day intervals to make the QA/QC more manageable. Since I'm crossing from 099 - 100 in the glob, I have to use brace expansion to match the correct sequence of days.

```
    ls -d /root_driectory/r18_{0[6-9]?,1[0-1]?}
    ls -d /root_driectory/r18_{060..119}
```

All of these work fine when I manually input these globs into my bash shell, but I get an error when the system() function provides a similar command through R.

```
    day_glob <- {060..119}
    system(paste("zcat /root_directory/r_18.", day_glob, "/fl.???.gz > tmpfile", sep = "")
    >gzip: cannot access '/root_directory/r18_{060..119}': No such file or directory
```

I know that this could be an error in the shell that the system() function operates in, but when I query that it gives the correct environment and user name

```
    system("env | grep ^SHELL=")
    >SHELL=/bin/bash 
    system("echo $USER")
    >tgw
```

Does anyone know why this fails when it is passed through R's system() command? What can I do to get around this problem without removing the system call altogether? There are many scripts that rely on these functions, and re-writing the entire family of R scripts would be time prohibitive.

Previously I had been using 50-day intervals which avoids this problem, but I thought this should be something easy to change, and make one less iteration of my QA/QC scripts per year. I'm new to the linux OS so I figured I might just be missing something obvious.

Comment: R's `system` and `system2` are broken in my eyes, so I try to rely on them as little as possible. You should be able to use `system("ls r18_{0[6-9],1[01]}*")`, though (the question mark doesn't work).

Comment: Yeah, with the amount of fiddly things I've tried, it doesn't seem like the system functions are working as intended. I actually found a similar problem/solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/40845667/7496750, but it only worked with the {060..119} format, and it still gave an error when commas were in the {}. Thanks, anyway!